# Powershell - compare two strings and highlight different words inside the strings

Tags: powershell, compare

I have two text files:

*First.txt*

```
SystemName Name                                          State   StartMode
---------- ----                                          -----   ---------
COMP-7     AdobeARMservice                               Running Auto     
COMP-7     Server2                                       Running Auto
```

*Second.txt*

```
SystemName Name                                          State   StartMode
---------- ----                                          -----   ---------
COMP-7     AdobeARMservice                               Stopped Auto  
COMP-7     Server2                                       Running Manual
```

I need a way to compare the txt files and output:

- The lines which are different (just like Compare-Object does)
- The different words inside the lines highlighted (in any way, different color for example)

So in this example, it would return something like this

> COMP-7     AdobeARMservice                               **Running**
>   Auto
>
> COMP-7     AdobeARMservice                               **Stopped**
>   Auto
>
> COMP-7     Server2                                       Running
>   **Auto**
>
> COMP-7     Server2                                       Running
>   **Manual**

Comment: To give you something to start with: If your files are so pretty like these that you postet: Go ahead and import them as CSV (delimiter `t might work). The resulting objects can be compared by `Compare-Object`. It would be easier, if you get the objects at the moment when the textfiles are created, or if you change the txt output to csv output (or something else that is structured)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll try to play around with that.